# Unhandled rejection TypeError: Dependency name must be given as a not empty string

Tags: sequelize.js, hapi.js

I got this error when codes hitting `require('./models').sequelize.sync()`. (`models` is a directory created by running command `sequelize init`) Could anyone give me some hints about what induces this error?

```
> node src/server.js

Unhandled rejection TypeError: Dependency name must be given as a not empty string
    at /Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/toposort-class/toposort.js:37:31
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Toposort.self.add (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/toposort-class/toposort.js:35:22)
    at /Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model-manager.js:89:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ModelManager.forEachModel (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model-manager.js:58:15)
    at /Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:862:23
    at tryCatcher (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:454:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:530:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAtPostResolution (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:224:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:182:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:187:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/syg/Repos/example/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

I'm using `sequelize@3.2.0` with `HapiJS`. An similar repo can be found [here](https://github.com/njj/hapi-rest-demo). (This repo is indeed working, even with `sequelize` upgraded to latest version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's caused by a illformed self-referencing key in one one of my model file.

Comment: Do you have more precision?

Comment: @user1843507 I don't have codes with me now, but you might as well look at your codes that specify 1toN/MtoN relationships carefully, especially variable names.

Comment: E.g. I had old school DB, without real foreign keys, connections (foreign keys) were just plain Integers so registering them as FK-s in models threw error.

Answer (score 21):

It was due to declaring of foreign key according to previous version of sequelize.

As per latest version "sequelize": "^4.31.2", correct way to add foreign key is-

```
addressId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
        model: 'addresses',
        key: 'id'
    }
}
```

I was declaring it as

```
addressId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: 'addresses',
    referencesKey: 'id'
}
```